# Scrape Goutte and waiting for full loading

Tags: php, symfony, scrape, goutte

I try to scrape via Goutte list from popular auction web service, but pieces of they code are rendered by javascript and problem is that Goutte return me only DOM without JS job. So if symphony are headless browser is it posiibile to wait with scraping until full content is rendered? I checked phantomjs where is normal, but I've never found that ability in Goute..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte**

Goutte does not parse Javascript, it is not a headless browser it just downloads the content and parse it without running javascript.

Technical Information

Goutte is a thin wrapper around the following fine PHP libraries:

Symfony Components: BrowserKit, CssSelector and DomCrawler;
Guzzle HTTP Component.

Comment: pity, I thought that since the symophony is built on WebKit it has similar capabilities to Phantomjs with which I have continus problems

Comment: it is not based on webkit. It is completely build in php and it does not have a full browser to render javascript. Can you accept the answer as valid if this answers your question?

Comment: I have already seen in the documentation a description that Symfony does not support JS but I thought that it is about actions, such as JS on click etc. During work, I got into suspicions and now with your help I gained confidence that I can not do what I can do with Goutte :-( pitty, I return to nodejs, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4):

You can use **symfony/panther** ([github](https://github.com/symfony/panther)/[packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/panther)), which is a headless browser that does interpret javascript and is already supporting *Symfony 5*, plus is an official package! Normally you would use it for testing purposes, but I think you might get the results you want.

You should replace your *Goutte* with *Panther*:

```php
$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createFirefoxClient();
```

And then tell your crawler to wait for an element to be present:

```php
$crawler = $client->waitFor('#javascript-generated-element');
```